# Sequence of numbers with constraints

Tags: algorithm

I have a sequence of positive numbers x_1,x_2,...x_n and I want to find a consecutive subsequence where:   0< x_i-x_j < i-j , 1<= j< i <= n   holds for all i,j . Define  S(t) to be the length of the longest consecutive sequence ending in x_t..

e.g. if
S(t) = 3  then the above holds for x_t,x_{t-1},x_{t-2}

I am trying to find a recursion formula, and I am completely stuck. I tried play around a little with numbers in order to find some pattern:

S(5) = 2 would mean that S(5) = 2 + S(4)  and S(4) must be $0$.But then maybe  S(3) could be 1 so we must stop as soon as we found out that S(4) = 0

Base cases or maybe special cases  S(0) = 0 ,S(1) = 0?

Is it possible to write S(k) in terms of S(k-1)?

I am trying to construct  an algorithm for this but first I need to figure out a recursion formula.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by "consecutive subsequence" and "numbers"? From the name, it sounds like it should be consecutive integers -- for example, the largest consecutive subsequence of 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4 would be 2, 3, 4, 5. But that doesn't satisfy the definition you provide.

Comment: In your recurrence a sequence of 1 seems to be invalid. Is this by mistake or on purpose? It definitely contradicts the usual definition of sequence.

Answer (score 0):

S(0) = 0 
If (x_n <= x_{n-1} or x_n - x_{n-1} >= 1) => S(n) = 0 
else if S(n-1) = 0 => S(n)=2 
else S(n) = S(n-1) + 1

Comment: Not sure if result  will be 1 rather than 0 int the question 'Base cases or maybe special cases S(0) = 0 ,S(1) = 0 ' so it seems the function would have 0,2,3... as result but never 1

Comment: Didn't notice that tweak. I guess this needs some clarification from OP.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for dynamic programming or recursion in this problem due to a simple relation of the comparison operator: it's transitive. This means:

```
a < b and b < c => a < c
```

We can transform the above inequality a bit:

```
x_i - x_j < i - j
x_i - i < x_j - j
```

This makes the whole problem a lot simpler:
Define a sequence `y`, where `y_i = x_i - i`. Find the longest strictly decreasing sequence ending at `y_t`.

Due to transitivity in a strictly decreasing sequence your condition always holds and vice versa. In fact these two constraints are equivalent in this case, as there can't be a constraint that is both decreasing and not violating the constraints on the sequence. So there's no need for recursion in this case at all, since the linear relationship is totally sufficient (transitivity).

Of course you could translate this search for the first non-decreasing pair into a recursive function (though it's more complicated than just going the linear path):

```
S(t) = {t = 0:                             0
        t = 1:                             1
        {x_t - t >= x_{t-1} - (t - 1)}:    1
        else:                              1 + S(t - 1)}
```